# Laravel Sanctum auth route is showing unautheticaed only in production

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

Hi I have recently set up my laravel 8 app with sanctum as api token provider.
my login works fine and token is received. this token I am using to get the user.. which works fine for me in localhost..

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

but when I deployed the same application to production.. get user is always resulting to "Unauthenticated".
I am not using SPA, and only wish to use API tokens
my production API path is like this
https://www.fbresident.fretbox.in/api/user
I have already set this to my .env file
SESSION_DOMAIN=.fretbox.in
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=fretbox.in
the SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS I have already tried changing to fbresident.fretbox.in

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having a similar issue in production. Users can't stary authenticated. Have you tried addinng this rule to ´.htaccess´? ´RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]´ as per documents state: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#a-note-on-fastcgi

Comment: Fer Toasted comment works

Answer (score 2):

just add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

in .htaccess file or follow documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#a-note-on-fastcgi

Comment: this saved lots of time +1

Answer (score 0):

I added edit config in .htaccess and it works

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization}
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```